# How to unit test async React hook state initializer?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a React hook that starts off in a loading state, then calls an async API from a repository object and then sets some state. I have created an in memory repository object, so my tests don't actually do any sort of fetching.

The problem is that I am getting an error saying that I am updating state outside of an `act` call.

> console.error
> Warning: An update to TestComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

```
When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
/* assert on the output */

This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
    at TestComponent (/home/ben-mclean/projects/E-Cad/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:278:5)

  25 |     const documents = [...all].map((s) => DrawingDocument.makeFromSnapshot(s));
  26 |
> 27 |     setState({ loading: false, documents });
     |     ^
  28 |   }, [repo]);
  29 |
  30 |   useEffect(() => {
```

This is my hook:

```
export function useDocumentList(
  repo: Repository<DrawingDocumentSnapshot>
): DocumentListResult {
  const [state, setState] = useState<DocumentListResult>(INITIAL_STATE);

  const initialize = useCallback(async () => {
    const all = await repo.getAll();
    const documents = [...all].map((s) => DrawingDocument.makeFromSnapshot(s));

    setState({ loading: false, documents });
  }, [repo]);

  useEffect(() => {
    initialize();
  }, [initialize]);

  return state;
}
```

This is my test:

```
  it('Loads the initial list.', async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useDocumentList(repo));

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(result.current.loading).toBe(false);
    });

    const actual = result.current;
    const expected = [doc1, doc2, doc3];

    expect(actual.loading).toBe(false);
    expect(haveSameItems(actual.documents, expected)).toBe(true);
  });
```

I have tried wrapping every combination of things in that test with an `act`. **The test passes**, but I still am getting this error. I would like to fix it, and not just silence it. Any help would be much appreciated, I will be writing quite a bit of code like this and I need to be able to test it.